# Resizing the preview layer based on the aspect ratio of the video frame

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to do iOS screen recording of the device connected to the system. I have an NSView which holds an videoView of type AVCaptureView. I have added a sublayer (previewLayer) to the videoView which displays preview of the video frames.I am trying to maintain the aspect ratio of the previewLayer as well as the videoView based on the first frame size of the video got from the iOS screen recording.

```html
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    if(imageBuffer != NULL)
    {
        CGSize imageSize = CVImageBufferGetDisplaySize(imageBuffer);
        NSLog(@"imageSize = %@", NSStringFromSize(imageSize));
        CGRect bounds = CGRectZero;
        bounds.size = imageSize;
        CGRect superViewBounds = streamingView.bounds;
         NSLog(@"superViewBounds = %@", NSStringFromRect(superViewBounds));
        if(bounds.size.width>superViewBounds.size.width || bounds.size.height>superViewBounds.size.height)
        {
            CGFloat ratio_width = bounds.size.width/superViewBounds.size.width;
            CGFloat ratio_height = bounds.size.height/superViewBounds.size.height;
            CGFloat ratio;
            if (ratio_width > ratio_height)
            {
                ratio = ratio_width;
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = ratio_height;
            }
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width/ratio;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.height/ratio;
            bounds.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(superViewBounds)-CGRectGetMidX(bounds);
            bounds.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(superViewBounds)-CGRectGetMidY(bounds);
            NSLog(@"bounds calculation = %@", NSStringFromRect(bounds));
        }
        [self.previewLayer setFrame:bounds];
         NSLog(@"preview layer = %@", NSStringFromRect(self.previewLayer.frame));
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
        [self.previewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorWhite)];
        [_videoView setFrame:bounds];
    }
}
```

Output

Image 1 - when the view is loaded for the first time in Portrait mode
[image]
Image 2 - when the iOS device orientation changes to landscape mode
[image]
Image 3 - when the iOS device is oriented back to portrait mode
[image]

if the device is such left as it is without changing orientation
I get the following log

CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

then on changing the orientation of device it appears as following
[image]